# Why do 10Ge intefaces show up a p55p1 and p55p2

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, networking, 14.10, nic

I just installed to 10GE nics into servers running 14.04 and 14.10 and the interface names show up as p55p1 and p55p2. Why is that ? When I added 10GE nics to 12.04 boxes the nics just came up as eth2 and eth3 since eth0 and eth0 are onboard nics.

ifconfig -a
...

```
p55p1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr x:x:x:x:x:x
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

p55p2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr x:x:x:y:y:y
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 0):

These are based on the [consistent device naming scheme](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Network_Device_Naming) established to avoid devices names to be reassigned to devices when some are added or removed.